# grails remoting plugin - always 404?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, remoting, httpinvoker

I'm trying to expose a remote interface to a spring web application, and I'm having issues, always getting 404. What's wrong with my setup below?

*Grails*:
**services - package mypackage**

```
class RemoteUserService implements RemoteUserServiceInterface {
    static expose = ['httpinvoker']

    User findUser(String userId) {
        return User.findByUserId(userId);
    }
}
```

**src/groovy/mypackage**

```
class RemoteUserService implements RemoteUserServiceInterface {
    static expose = ['httpinvoker']

    User findUser(String userId) {
        return User.findByUserId(userId);
    }
}
```

*Spring:*
**mypackage**

```
public class MyController extends AbstractController {
    RemoteUserServiceInterface remoteUserService
}
```

**appContext**

```
<bean id="viewController" class="mypackage.MyController">
    <property name="remoteUserService" ref="remoteUserService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="remoteUserService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/grails-app-name/httpinvoker/RemoteUserService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="mypackage.RemoteUserServiceInterface"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: (1) In your problem description, I believe you copy/pasted your service code where you should have copy/pasted your interface code. (2) Do you get a 404 error when going to 'http://localhost:8080/grails-app-name/httpinvoker/RemoteUserService' via your browser? Or is this just a problem when connecting using your remote MyController?

Comment: I get a 404 if I go to this directly in the browser. The interface just defines the single method available in the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a UrlMapping of

`"$controller/$action?/$id?" {}`

or else the plugin won't work correctly.